Why is this argument valid?
I m reading Linnet's paper 'pluralities and set' where his claim said that collapse principle lead contradiction if we didn't assume 'it is possible to quantify over absolutely everything'
He uses plural quantifiers and demonstrates Russell's paradox using the collapse principle and the plural comprehension principle, describing the situation that arises if we do not assume that it is possible to quantify over absolutely everything. First, the formalization of Russell's argument and his claim are as follows:


However, I don't understand how the scope of the universal quantifier in (1) can be smaller than the existential quantifier in (2) without assuming that we are quantifying over absolutely everything. For example, even if we assume that all the objects we can handle are {a, b, c, d, e}, and the domain of the argument is {a, b, c}, I still don't see how this can happen. As far as I know, even if the domain dealt with in the argument is not the whole but limited, the maximum scope of the existential quantifier can at best only extend to the domain that the universal quantifier covers.
i'm not sure what it means to say that the scope of the quantifier in step (1) of the argument can be different from the scope of the quantifier in step (2), and therefore ∃ can be larger than ∀

Maybe Øystein Linnebo

The issue seems to be with the usual "model" of set theory as an "open ended" hierarchy... If so, we may say that we have no clear intuition of what the phrase "all sets" means. Maybe useful Charles Parsons, Sets and classes (Nous, 1974).

Nitpicking comemnt: I do not think that the tag Value Pluralism is correct here...

What I don't understand here is how the scope of the domain on which the expression 'for all u' in (1) is based can differ from the scope of the domain on which the expression 'for some r' in (2) is based. While the scope of u and r may vary depending on the scope of the subsequent expressions, 'for all u' clearly refers to the entire domain(no matter how to entire domain justified, it can have one elements, though we handle more than one), and 'for some r' refers at most to a range that the entire domain can indicate.

However, Linnebo criticizes Russell's paradox by stating that if it is not guaranteed that we definitively quantify over the entire set, 'for some r' can be larger than 'for all u'. But based on the definition of quantifier expressions, when the domain is fixed, the 'for some' symbol and the 'for all' symbol share the same domain, and therefore, the range that the 'for some' symbol can take is always smaller than that of the 'for all' symbol.

However, the critique here seems to suggest that when we fix one domain and argue, the range that the 'for some' symbol takes can be smaller than the range that the 'for all' symbol takes.

THe "technical" gist is the refutation of the (common) assumption that "is possible to quantify over absolutely everything". If we reject it, we can imagine that the outer existential range over a "level" of the hierarchy that is above (and thus larger) the level of the domain of the inner universal. Thus, the set r that exists in the upper level does not necessarily exist in the lower one that means that we cannot use it (the same r) to instantiate the universal quantiifer and the contradicition has been blocked.

if assumption is rejected, then even within a single argument, as suggested by the presented objection, is it logically consistent to assume a higher level such as x+1 when using the quantifier symbol in other subsequent lines of the same argument, even if a certain level 'x' of hierarchy is assumed by the expression 'for all u' in the first line of the argument?

So, are you pointing out that if the universal set can continue to expand, then the assumed scope might change even among the quantifiers used in the stages of the argument as it progresses?

It's the same root cause in one of your own recent post in this site...
